# How this DAG topological restructuring can be called?

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I had interest in Direct Acyclic Graphs (DAG) for a long time and after reading about Topological sort at Wikipedia, I did not find any special mentioning of an approach involving **layers numbering** (although layers are extensively mentioned for drawing). With this approach the graph is not technically topologically sorted, but knowing that every node contains the correct number for layer (level), we always can tell whether a particular node "bigger" than another topologically. On the other side as long as we don't have an ordered list, we can not enumerate the nodes topologically (although this can be done with a final conventional sort that compares the levels of the nodes).

This approach allows implementing arbitrary connecting while maintaining the correctness of levels information. The steps can be:

- For any newly added node (without any connection) the level applied is 1.
- If a connection between two nodes is requested (from m to n) and the n.level > m.level then they are just simply being connected, no level fixing for other nodes is required.
- If for requested connection (from m to n) n.level<=m.level then we change n.level to (m.level + 1) and recursively check any dependencies of n for similar level increase (or no increase if the levels on a recursive step are compatible).
- If we keep the list of recursively entered nodes then we can detect an attempt to cycle and implement some kind of undo operation (returning the levels of all affected nodes to previous values)

For any set of known nodes and connections between them, we just add all nodes applying level=1 to them and just try to apply all known connections between (ignoring and undoing cicles).

The final level information not only allows comparing nodes topologically, but contains other useful information. For example:

- every node with level = 1 has no incoming connections (every path starts from one of them). So any DAG enumeration can be started from them.
- The longest path (the number of edges) can not be longer than the (largest level + 1)

I suppose that for some artificial data (n nodes, every Node(n) connected to Node(n + 1)) this algorithm can be very slow. But for real-world data I tried it with (Wikipedia categories - 800,000 nodes - 2,000,000 connections) the time is decent (5-10 minutes) and the number of levels and cycle attempts is low (369 levels, 1000 cycle attempts)

So is this method new or is well-known, but just not widely presented in Wikipedia and other resources? Since it's not a sort (technically), should it be called a data restructuring?

Comment: This question really belongs on the Computer Science stack exchange - Stack Overflow is for questions we can answer with code.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider posting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some papers on incrementally maintaining the topological order of nodes in a graph, with variations on the algorithm you describe.

If the graph has `n` nodes and `m` edges, you spend time `O(m + n)` every time you insert an edge. 
The papers ask how much time will it take to insert `k` edges? Trivially, `O(k * (n + m))`. But in fact you can show much better upper bounds - something like `O(k * sqrt(m + n))` for large enough `k`.

Some links below, there are more:

http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/math/2007-0725-201647/2005-011.pdf

http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.1059

http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2009/SODA09_120_benderm.pdf

Comment: Great, seems like it's Bender-Fineman-Gilbert presented on SODA 2009 (your last link). Pity to hear, the creation date of my unit implementing the algorithm is 2004. I was sure this was something obvious so never tried to find out how it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Probably someone has thought of this before, but since its worst-case is linear, I would be hard pressed to point you to a research article where it's described. The name for the problem this algorithm solves is "incremental topological sorting" (or dynamic, where edge deletions are also possible).

Answer (score 1):

Consider a DAG consisting of two "parallel" directed paths of length `n` sharing the starting node and the last node. The layer numbering here is more restrictive than the topological order. In the topological order you can put next-to-last node from path A before second node from path B even though its layer number is larger.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the actual implementation I described will never set a number for particular node higher than for for other node if not for relation. So let's the points A, B, C, D and the first path A(1)-B(2)-D(4) and the second A(1)-C(3)-D(4) (levels are in the brackets). So B and C here are at the different levels only because there is some F(2) connected to C that forced it to the next level, otherwise they would live together on the same level (2). And in case of this affecting F conventional topological sort can not make B and C interchangeable

Comment: @Maksee This is only because both paths are only 2 edges long. Increase the length and you'll get more than 1 layer within each path.

Comment: I see, you're right. Here we get minimum layer, the maximum is the minimum of the depended layers minus one. For behave like topological sort when comparing two nodes we should intersect min-max cuts, if they intersect, the nodes are topologically equivalent. if not - the results depends on which is higher